# Nested resources or not for categories?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an application, built with Rails 3.1.3, that has products and categories. The categories are related to other categories, so a category can be a parent or a child category. The products are then related to a child category.

Now, I'm thinking about how I should define the routes. Is it a good idea to somehow nest the categories and products resources? Ideally, I would like URLs like this:

```
example.com/parent/child/product-1234

like this:
example.com/clothes/underwear/some-socks-1234

or maybe like this to keep it restful?
example.com/p/clothes/c/underwear/....
```

But maybe that's a bit messy to achieve with the routes? I would have to nest the category with itself I guess?

Any ideas on how to achieve something like this?

**EDIT:**
Do I create the category routes like this:

```
resources :categories, :as => "parent" do
    resources :categories, :as => "child"
end
```

or similar? It's not that important to have the product nested inside the categories. Maybe it will just make it hard to manage...

Comment: Rails does have built-in support for ids in URLs that are of the form '12345-some-textual-name'.  The non-numeric portion gets dropped for the controller but it makes for nicer looking URL slugs.

Comment: @Nick Yes. But what about the actual nesting? Can I do something like what I added to my original question? Nest it inside itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either be RESTful or not, you can't have it both ways.

If Category is a resource, then you can define routes with `resource :categories` statement and use Rails built-in support for REST. But then all categories should be accessible through `categories/id`. If you want different categories be accessible through different routes, then you are not RESTful and you can't use Rails REST support.

Alternatively you can say that parent and child categories are different resources and be RESTful again.

**Edit:** looking at my answer now (after it was accepted) I feel like I was probably too stiff. The answer should probably be "it depends" (as usual). If the application is CRUD (admin), I would stick to plain categories and nested products (shallow). On the storefront where you need nice looking url you can totally have non-REST routes and actions. It just mean more coding.

Answer (score 1):

I would add an extra route besides the RESTful ones to support your URLs. This ignores the categories (they don't even have to exist) and routes directly to the product.

```
  ...

  resources :products
  resources :categories

  match ':parent/:child/:product' => "products#show"

  ...
```

In your show action you can simply check which of `params[:product]` and `params[:id]` that is set and handle the different routes. 
`params[:parent]` and `params[:child]` will also be available but i would suggest just looking for the product and get the category through that object since that should be more reliable.